# Migrating to a Field Collection

Tags: 7, migrations, entities

I'm working on a project that requires a CSV of speaking engagements to be migrated to Drupal. With Migrate, I've been able to migrate over basic fields, like name, title, etc.

However, the `speaker` field is a field collection, which is driving me nuts. While the field collection allows unlimited speakers, the CSV only has one per event. I've tried using the `node_insert` hook, as described [here](http://karenziv.com/2012/10/migrating-drupal-6-multigroups-to-drupal-7-field-collections/) but to no avail. Is there a better/easier way to migrate a single speaker into the speaker field collection?

Answer (score 5):

There is a [Field Collection issue](https://drupal.org/node/1175082) with a Field Collection Migrate destination (in the patch in comment #222). The added `field_collection.migrate.inc` file contain a bit of documentation on how to use it.

In you case, I guess you have a speaking engagements migration class which load your CSV file and create Speaking engagement nodes. You will then need a speaker migration class to load the same CSV file and create Speaker field collections. This second migration class depends on the first one, so when a Speaker is created, it will be linked to its Speaking engagement.

Something like

```
class SpeakerMigration extends Migration {

  public function __construct($arguments) {
    parent::__construct($arguments);
    $this->dependencies = array('SpeakingEngagementMigration');
    $this->source = new MigrateSourceCSV('path/to/speaking/engagement.csv', array(), array());
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationFieldCollection('field_speakers',array('host_entity_type' => 'node'));
    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName, array(
      'id' => array(
        'type' => 'char',
        'length' => 40,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'description' => t("Speaking Engagement's identifier"),
      )), MigrateDestinationFieldCollection::getKeySchema());
    $this->addFieldMapping('host_entity_id', 'id')
      ->sourceMigration('SpeakingEngagementMigration');

    // ... Add field mapping here.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the implement the `complete` method of the `Migration` class and populate the field collection programmatically there.

```
public function complete($entity, $row) {

  // load the newly created node (just in case entity isn't fully populated).
  $node = node_load($entity->nid);

  // set the values of all field collection fields
  $values = array(
    'field_name' => 'FIELD_COLLECTION_ITEM_FIELD_NAME',
    'field1'     => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => 'VALUE'))),
    'field3'     => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => 'VALUE'))),
  );

  // create the field collection item entity
  $item = entity_create('field_collection_item', $values);

  // attach it to the node loaded above
  $item->setHostEntity('node', $node);

  // save the entity
  $item->save();
}
```

**NOTE**: If you are adding files to the field collection item, they will not be removed on a rollback unless you explicitly do that.